# Persisting a login with the Slack API

Tags: authentication, authorization, backend, slack-api

I currently have this flow but I am unsure of the architecture going forward.

1. On my page, the user gets sent to the Slack OAuth API where they confirm scopes
2. User gets redirected back to my page with a one time code
3. Client sends a request to the server with the code
4. The server sends a request to Slack with the code, exchanging it for an access token
5. If the code and token are OK, it creates a new user in MongoDB

I made a flowchart to illustrate:
[image]

I would like the user to not have to authorize the scopes every time they want to access the service, and even if they did, how would I keep the token around in a secure manner to make requests? Would I have to create my own token authentication with login and password, or is there a better way? Should I persist this token on the client somehow and have the users be logged in that way? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Slack token generation must be one time activity per user.

 When creating user in MongoDB, you should also store the generated token securely.

For later use, your application should use the stored token for any slack interactions, 
given that you have authenticated the user whose token you'll be using.